# Combine tuple and list into list-of-lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm very new to programming and trying to combine a list and tuple into a new list:

- *goods* is a tuple of commodities.
- Each commodity has a corresponding price, generated at random and saved in the list *prices*
- I want a list called *offer* assigning the corresponding price value to each commodity from *goods*

I'd be very grateful for a simple solution and also a brief explanation why my attempt only returns a value for cloth (I entered range 0:5 but it seems just to return element 4, cloth and its price)

```
import random

goods = ("Silk", "Gems", "Wool", "Hide", "Cloth", "Iron")

def set_prices ():

    price_s = random.randrange(180,300)
    price_g = random.randrange(250,800)
    price_w = random.randrange(1,5)
    price_h = random.randrange(5,18)
    price_c = random.randrange(20,50)
    price_i = random.randrange(50,150)

    prices = [price_s,price_g,price_w,price_h,price_c,price_i]

    for n in range (0,5):
        offer = [(goods[n],prices[n])] 
        print (offer)

set_prices()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: The right boundary of ranges and slices is excluded by convention in python. So range(0,5) runs from 0 to 4 inclusive.

Comment: Do you really mean that you *only* see the entry for cloth? That is what I can't reproduce. What does happen is that it *stops* at cloth, for the reason that @PaulPanzer gives. Another issue - in your loop you are creating a new list in each pass. You would need to append to a growing list if you want `offer` to contain the list of all offers after the loop is done.

Comment: If both `goods` and `prices` have the same number of elements, consider using `zip`: `for good, price in zip(goods, prices): offer = [(good, price)]`

Comment: A dict of `{'commodity':price}` is a much more Pythonic idiom than list-of-lists. Also easier to look up, and iterate over. `{commodity:price} for commodity in goods for price in prices}`

Comment: List-of-lists suggests you're not familiar with Python idiom. It's practically an antipattern. Are you coming from PERL, PHP, Java or C++? (`range(len(...))` is also an antipattern). Don't just learn the language syntax, learn the idiom...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `range(0,5)` will only produce `0,1,2,3,4`, as the `5` is excluded. An easy solution is to use `range(len(goods))`, to produce a range with the same number of values of goods:

```
for n in range(len(goods)):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through both lists simultaneously:

```
for offer in zip(goods,prices):
    print(offer)
```

This produces output as a tuple:

```
('Silk', 276)
('Gems', 486)
...
```

but can be converted to a list with `list(offer)`:

```
['Silk', 188]
['Gems', 620]
['Wool', 2]
['Hide', 14]
['Cloth', 38]
['Iron', 130]
```

Comment: `zip(l1,l2)` is so much nicer and less clunky idiom than `range(len(...))`

Comment: Yes, it looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Actually a dict of `{'commodity':price}` is a much more Pythonic idiom than list-of-lists. Also easier to look up, and iterate over. `{commodity:price} for commodity in goods for price in prices}`

Comment: I think `{commodity:price for commodity,price in zip(goods,prices)}` is perhaps nicer.

Comment: I was thinking of that, too. Depends on what the OP's familiar with. Non-Python people may prefer the former, it makes everything explicit. But, both are great.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my code to create the list of lists and that works. Now trying to improve on it using a dictionary instead but having trouble adding keys and values with a loop  offer={}
 
 for x in range (0,5):
     offer[goods[x]] = prices[x]
  
 return {offer}

Comment: @Devon: stop this loop stuff already! Learn proper idiom. Do `{commodity:price for commodity,price in zip(goods,prices)}`. That's called a dict comprehension. That's all you need. Unlearn the bad habit of explicitly managing list-indices every time you want to iterate over a list. Learn to do list comprehensions/dict comprehensions, iterate... look at the `.items()` method on tuples, lists and dicts. Welcome to Python ;-)